# Altium trace length vs signal length

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, pcb-fabrication

I've seen both of these in the PCB tab when editing the PCB board in Altium Designer.. what are the two?
I thought I new, but I have fully routed traces with signal lengths of 0 as well as signal and trace lengths that are totally different from each other.  As well as sometimes signal lengths go up and down with the trace lengths as I'm routing, but other times the signal lengths do not change...

What are these two things, how are they related, and how do I edit signal lengths? (I'm assuming I'm right in thinking trace lengths are determined by the physically routed length of the traces.  If not then please explain).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to Altium's forum please look at these two threads:
https://forum.live.altium.com/#posts/215294
https://forum.live.altium.com/#posts/215784

If you have no access, the basics are:

Routed length - sum of all segments of a net. Having overlapping segments will give falsely larger numbers.

Signal length - calculated as length of path along a net between two pads. Signal length = 0 means there are either 1 or 3+ pads in the net. Altium can only calculate signal length for a 2-pad net.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what **possible** asinine reason Altium could have to prevent anonymous people from *reading* their help forums. I can't think of anything.

Answer (score 1):

**A slightly edited copy-paste from the Altium forum:**

> A quick definition of the two terms:
>
> **Routed length** - Calculated as length of all routed segments of net.
>
> **Signal length**  - Calculated as signal path from source pad to
> destination pad.
>
> TechDocs link: [Accurate Route Length Calculation (New Feature Summary)](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/nfs-15-0accurate-route-length-calculation-ad?version=15.1)
>
> Signal length = 0 means net contains only 1 pad or more than 2 pads.
> (Currently, the signal length calculation is only defined for direct, pin-to-pin connections. **For more than 2 pads**, it will be necessary to **define xSignals**
> and use the xSignal section.)